# Chocolatey install Error: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: ssl, chocolatey

I'm getting the following error when installing Chocolatey - 'https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'

Error 
`The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like the security protocol changed:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`

Comment: Thank you.  Instlaling Choco on Server 2016 fails otherwise.